# In which case user can clear shared preferences but not DB

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, android-memory, android-database

As I know, when a user does "clear data" or "disable" any application, it's shared preferences are cleared and database is also cleared.

So my question is,

**Is there any case, that user can perform, in which shared preferences gets cleared but database remains intact ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clear Data** will clear everything, Shared Preference, Cache, DB.

If you really want to clear only shared preference (some/all) you can do it programmatically by iterating over Shared Preferences like this:

```
Map<String, ?> allEntries = prefA.getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
    Log.i("debug", entry.getKey() + ": " +  entry.getValue().toString());
    //put delete/edit logic here for some shared preference
}
```

This logic can be placed based on your app version, or some other logic like when user logs out, but this action would be performed in your app only.

I dont think Android Applications settings allows any option where you can clear only shared preferences and not local db.

Answer (score 3):

Clear data means user wants to clean complete data related to app (sharedpref, cache, db). If you want some data to remain intact even after user tap on "clear data", keep in device storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save an ArrayList of Objects in Shared Preferences.

From Android Documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

> The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows
>   you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of **primitive
>   data types.** You can use SharedPreferences to save any **primitive
>   data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings.** This data will
>   persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

The easiest solution would be to implement serializable in your objects and save them in internal storage.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: As, I mentioned, "I should save that list as String in SharedPreferences or keep it in database." that is pretty clear to me. You answered what I did not ask

Comment: Be thankful someone is taking the time to answer you. Here you are saying you want an arrayList of objects to be remained intact ? How is saving strings helping you keep the objects intact ? Provide code so we can see exactly what you are doing and above all fix your attitude.

Comment: I think the question was a bit misleading, sorry for that.
I have edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to put a database in apk [directly](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). Of course if you use already completed database in your case